# Sort a list of dicts by multiple items AND different reverse values for each item

Tags: python

I have the following list of objects and I want to sort them such that first all dicts with `k2 == True` (alphabetically ordered A-Z) and afterwards all dicts with `k2 == False` (alphabetically ordered A-Z). 
I tried something like this `sorted(test, key=lambda k: (k['k2'], k['k1'].lower()), reverse=(True,False))` but it doesn't work.

```
>>> test = [
...     {"k1": "qsd", "k2": True},
...     {"k1": "JKd", "k2": False},
...     {"k1": "Ukz", "k2": False},
...     {"k1": "aqd", "k2": True},
...     {"k1": "Asd", "k2": True},
...     {"k1": "wef", "k2": False},
...     {"k1": "Wgr", "k2": True},
...     {"k1": "weg", "k2": False},
...     {"k1": "lfe", "k2": True},
... ]
>>>
>>> test = sorted(test, key=lambda k: (k['k2'], k['k1'].lower()), reverse=True)
>>> for t in test:
...     print(t)
...
{'k1': 'Wgr', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'qsd', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'lfe', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'Asd', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'aqd', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'weg', 'k2': False}
{'k1': 'wef', 'k2': False}
{'k1': 'Ukz', 'k2': False}
{'k1': 'JKd', 'k2': False}
```

I'm looking for:

```
{'k1': 'aqd', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'Asd', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'lfe', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'qsd', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'Wgr', 'k2': True}
{'k1': 'JKd', 'k2': False}
{'k1': 'Ukz', 'k2': False}
{'k1': 'wef', 'k2': False}
{'k1': 'weg', 'k2': False}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, use `not k['k2']` for the first sorter.

```
>>> test.sort(key=lambda k: (not k['k2'], k['k1'].lower()))
>>> test
[{'k1': 'aqd', 'k2': True},
 {'k1': 'Asd', 'k2': True},
 {'k1': 'lfe', 'k2': True},
 {'k1': 'qsd', 'k2': True},
 {'k1': 'Wgr', 'k2': True},
 {'k1': 'JKd', 'k2': False},
 {'k1': 'Ukz', 'k2': False},
 {'k1': 'wef', 'k2': False},
 {'k1': 'weg', 'k2': False}]
```

`not k['k2']` is `False` when `k['k2']` is True, and False (=0) < True (=1).